# Spring 3 and Junit 4 NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, junit

I have a problem in setting up a unit test based on Spring 3 and Junit 4

My code is fairly basic at the moment as can be seen below

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

public class PSTemplateDAOTests { 

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(        
PSTemplateDAOTests.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext ctx;


    @Test
    public void testone ()
    {
        logger.info("Run testone");     
    }

    @Test
    public void testtwo ()
    {
        logger.info("Run testtwo");
    }
}
```

However when I come to run this I encounter a NPE as below :-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.resolveContextLoaderClass(ContextLoaderUtils.java:153)
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.resolveContextLoader(ContextLoaderUtils.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.ContextLoaderUtils.buildMergedContextConfiguration(ContextLoaderUtils.java:298)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.<init>(TestContext.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)

at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

If I comment out the @ContextConfiguration annotation the test(s) will run however then I encounter the following :-

```
May 20, 2015 8:28:29 AM org.springframework.test.context.TestContext  <init>
INFO: @ContextConfiguration not found for class [class    uk.gov.moj.ps.dao.PSTemplateDAOTests]
May 20, 2015 8:28:29 AM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager retrieveTestExecutionListeners
INFO: @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [class uk.gov.moj.ps.dao.PSTemplateDAOTests]: using defaults.
2015-05-20 08:28:29 INFO  PSTemplateDAOTests:34 - Run testtwo
2015-05-20 08:28:29 INFO  PSTemplateDAOTests:27 - Run testone
```

Which makes sense as there is no ContextConfiguration element to allow Spring to set up the environment.

I have also tried different ContextConfiguration set ups with both normal files and location elements, neither setting gets past the initial NPE error.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler and jre 1.7 although I have also switched round jre's without any success.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Ok - I realise I wasn't clear enough in my description, it is my first question on SO, anyway some further clarification.

I am aware that the contextconfiguration is generally configured with a path to a file via location or just a simple path, I have tried both of these and also the default value with no path.

The whole crux of the matter is that the @Contextconfiguration triggers a NPE regardless of what is supplied to it, in fact spring doesn't even seem to initialise correctly.

I hope this makes things clearer

Comment: How do you configure yoir contextconfiguration? Using xml files or annotations?

Comment: Do you not need to point your @ContextConfiguration to where it resides?  Example:  @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })

Answer (score 1):

Most examples from the Spring Framework Reference Manual explicitely defines the location of the XML file, or `@Configuration` classes used to populate the application context.

You can use a plain `@ContextConfiguration` annotation without any configuration, but the default may not be what you expect :

*If you omit both the locations and value attributes from the @ContextConfiguration annotation, the TestContext framework will attempt to detect a default XML resource location. Specifically, GenericXmlContextLoader detects a default location based on the name of the test class. If your class is named com.example.MyTest, GenericXmlContextLoader loads your application context from "classpath:/com/example/MyTest-context.xml".*

IMHO, you should explicitely pass the configuration of the application context to `@ContextConfiguration`. Examples from same doc :

```
// use test.config.xml from classpath
@ContextConfiguration("/test-config.xml")
public class XmlApplicationContextTests {
    // class body...
}

// use TestConfig as a @Configuration class
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class ConfigClassApplicationContextTests {
    // class body...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can autowire ApplicationContext like you are trying, and I'm not sure why you would want to, especially in a test.

But if you really want to, try the code below:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class PSTemplateDAOTests implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PSTemplateDAOTests.class.getName());

    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Test
    public void assertContextPreset() {
        Assert.notNull(ctx);
    }

    @Test
    public void testone() {
        logger.info("Run testone");
    }

    @Test
    public void testtwo() {
        logger.info("Run testtwo");
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        ctx = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Like others have said, you also seem to be missing some application context configuration. You should either provide a location as a parameter to `ContextConfiguration` or create a context file named `PSTemplateDAOTests-context.xml` in the same package as the test.